# Best practices - When to use Server / Client code

Tags: asp.net, ajax, client-server

I was searching for information about one of my doubts, but I couldn't find any. I'm working in an *ASP.NET* site and using *AJAX* to require data, since I'm currently working on my own, I don't know web programming's best practices.

I usually get all the information I need from the server and use Javascript to display / Modify it and *AJAX* to send it back to the server. A friend of mine uses PHP for most part of the programming, He rarelly uses any javascript and he told me it's way faster this way, since it does not consume the client's resources.

The basic question actually is:

> According to the best practices, is it better for the server just to provide the data needed for the
>   application or is better you use the server for more than this?

Comment: How do you friend think the content is loaded without using any recources? Unicorns?

Comment: In essence, the client should be responsible for making and sending requests to the server, then displaying any responses (i.e. AJAX, forms, hyperlinks, etc.). The server should handle all data processing.

Comment: @PeeHaa it consumes server's resources, not client's.

Comment: Ofc it uses client resources. How would the page be rendered. fairy dust?

Comment: Ask your friend how to do partial render(AJAX) without using JS ?

Comment: The best practices is use JS to write your own AJAX to work with service side resource.

Comment: @peehaa yeah, I know it, but the question was: what one should I focus the MOST part of the development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases you would need at least some backend code. E.g. when validating user input or when retrieving information from a real persistent database. Or what about when somebody has javascript disabled in his user-agent or somebody with a screenreader or searchengine crawlers?

IMHO you should at least (again in most cases) have the backend code which is able to do all the work and spit out a full webpage to the client. In addition to this you can add javascript functionality to make the user interface "smoother" by for example validating user data before submitting it to the server (remember to ALWAYS also check on the serverside) or by loading partial html (AJAX).

The point about being faster or using less resources when doing it serverside doesn't make much sense. Even if it does that it doesn't matter (but again I highly doubt this statement). If you use clientside scripting to only load parts that are needed it would rather use less resources on both the client- and the serverside.

Answer (score 2):

That is going to depend on the expected amount of traffic for the site, the amount of content being generated, and the expectations of the end-user.

In a high-traffic site, it is actually "faster" for the end-user if you let javascript generate a portion of the content on the client side. Also, you can deliver a better user experience with long load times through client side scripting than you can if the content is loaded completely on the server.